# Unity: Convert Vector2 to Vector2Int

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I have a `Vector2` and I want to convert it into a `Vector2Int`. I know I could convert the `Vector2` with something like this:

```
Vector2 v2 = new Vector2(10, 10);
Vector2Int v2i;

v2i = new Vector2Int((int) v2.x, (int) v2.y);
```

But is there a shorter or more effective way? For example something like this:

```
v2i = v2.toVector2Int();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a [built-in static method](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.RoundToInt.html) for this:

```
Vector2 v2 = new Vector2(10, 10);
Vector2Int v2i = Vector2Int.RoundToInt(v2);
```

You can also use Vector2Int.CeilToInt(Vector2 v) and Vector2Int.FloorToInt(Vector2 v) depending on what you need

Answer (score 5):

You can use extension methods to make it more readable:

```
public static Vector2Int ToInt2(this Vector2 v)
{
    return new Vector2Int((int)v.x, (int)v.y);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Vector2 v2 = new Vector2(10, 10);
Vector2Int v2i = v2.ToInt2();
```

Comment: Return value is incorrect, function header should be corrected to : 
public static Vector2Int ToInt2(this Vector2 v)

Answer (score -3):

You can use the [automapper](https://automapper.org/) library and let the library do the job for you.
The call would be something as:

```
Vector2Int v2i = Mapper.Map<Vector2>(v2);
```

The advantage of automapper is, that it is a very powerful tool that hides all this nasty mapping logic for you.